# Selenium webdriver: Connection refused (connection refused) error in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to set up selenium webdriver3.4 in Ubuntu14.04 . While running selenium script I'm getting HttpHostConnectionException error. Please find below the script that I have used and the error:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTest {
    WebDriver driver;
  @BeforeTest
  public void f() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","/usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
       }

     @Test
     public void approvelisting() 
     {
        driver.get("https://<domain name>/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
}
```

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.12.0
>   1507297197197   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.19.0
>   1507297197226   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:13663
>   FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest f
>   org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:13663 [localhost/127.1.0.0] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'admin-coddletech', ip: '127.0.0.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.16.0-30-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
>   Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

Please help me on troubleshooting this exception

Comment: Have you tried to open a different URL?

Comment: Please make sure you have entry of `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/etc/hosts` if there is any other IP for localhost then remove it. `Connect to localhost:13663 [localhost/127.1.0.0]` indicates localhost is for some reason going to `127.1.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks @Tarun it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have entry of `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/etc/hosts` if there is any other IP for localhost then remove it. Connect to `localhost:13663 [localhost/127.1.0.0]` indicates `localhost` is for some reason going to `127.1.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct it seems your local host is not setup properly.

it is running in my system and it is also running with different URL. I tried same code with another it is working fine. Change the port number of Localhost and try

This is my code:

```
public class Stackoverflow_demo {

    WebDriver driver;
      @BeforeTest
      public void f() {
          driver = new FirefoxDriver(); 
           }

         @Test
         public void approvelisting() 
         {
            driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(500, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      }
}
```

Comment: Yes. It's working. Thank you so much @Tarun Lalwani. I struggled with the issue more than a week

Comment: OK, Is my answer helps you Please Upvote, glad your problem is solved.